# .htaccess rewrite second parameter to directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like the last parameter/directory from the following urls:

```
http://example.com/movies/randomMovie
http://example.com/books/randomBook
```

to be passed like following:

```
http://example.com/movies.php?=randomMovie
http://example.com/books.php?=randomBook
```

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ movies.php?=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ books.php?=$1 [QSA]
```

But that overwrites the rule for (movies.php).

How do I achieve this in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is not matching `/movies/` and `/books/`, you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^movies/([^/]+)/?$ movies.php?=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^books/([^/]+)/?$ books.php?=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The server/client looks for randomMovie.php in the directory /movies/. It triggers the following error:
"Not Found
The requested URL /movies/randomMovie.php was not found on this server."

Comment: I placed it in the parent directories. Now it instead triggers: "The requested URL /movies/randomMovie was not found on this server."

Comment: Initially they were located in the parent folder. But I've tried adding them to subdirectories (/movies/ and /books/) as well as renaming them to index.php too without any success.

Comment: Did exactly as explained. Still getting: "The requested URL /movies/randomMovie.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117309/discussion-between-anubhava-and-henrik-sandstrom).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^movies/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ movies.php?=$1 [L, QSA]
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ books.php?=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: This triggers the following error:
"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: How you will access the param (randomMovie| randomBook), since $1 is not assigned to any query parameters. I checked this rule locally by assigning location=$1 and it worked.. Able to use location variable in movies.php

Comment: RewriteRule ^movies/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ movies.php?location=$1 [L, QSA]